# Typescript generics: infer type from the type of function arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a method that has 2 arguments and I want it to infer a type from the 1st argument.

For example, in the following code, I want the type `T` of the function `create_C<T>` to be inferred from the `firstArgument` so that the return type of  `create_C` function would be `C<type inferred from firstArgument>`

```
interface C<T> { 
    firstArgument: A<T>;
    secondArgument: (obj: any) => T
}

export interface A<T> {
    type: T;
}

function create_C<T>(
    firstArgument: A<T>,
    secondArgument: (obj: any) => T
): C<T> {
    return {
        firstArgument,
        secondArgument
    }
}
```

However, in the following implementation, the type of `const c` is being inferred as `C<{ prop2: number }>`. But I am expecting it to be inferred as `C<B>` and I am expecting the compiler to throw an error saying that the return type of the `secondArgument` is not of type `B`

```
interface B { 
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number
}

export class B_Component implements A<B> {
    type: B = {
        prop1: "",
        prop2: 1
    };
}

const c = create_C(
    new B_Component(),
    () => ({ prop2: 2 })
)
```

How can I make sure for the compiler to throw an error saying that the return type of the `secondArgument` is not of type `B`?

Here is a Stackblitz editor link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/qqddsn

Comment: Not totally following but shouldn't you call `create_C` like this?: `create_C<B_Component>()`. You type the function with a generic and all looks good, just need to pass the right type to T when you call it...

Comment: So do you want your `create_C` call to be an error?  The callback passed as the second parameter doesn't return a `B`, it returns a `{prop2: number}`, so `c` is a `C<{prop2: number}>`.  Why not return an actual `B` in the callback?

Comment: @MrRobboto i don't want to call the function with a generic. I want the generic to be inferred based on the type of first argument passed

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't have create_C typed as taking a generic then

Comment: And should read into @jcalz comment - `() => ({ prop2: 2 })` doesn't fit what you type with `secondArgument: (obj: any) => T`

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I want the ```create_C``` call to show an error saying that the callback passed as a 2nd parameter is not returning B. I want to enforce the user that is passing in the 2nd argument to return B. And if he is not, I want the type safety to shout at him with an error.

Comment: @PrudhviChandraSimhadri I see what you're saying now, not really clear in OP that the second example is supposed to throw an error.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIB4AqA+ZBvZAKGRORmCgGcwBBKAcwFcBbCcALmRq2wG5jSlCAgD2IACZ0mrDsgAUIgEYArTnBABPAJTIAvLkyEAvoUKhIsRCm458AkmA0AHCJ0z8ThGIxAIwwMWQEKAg4SAB9DBw5ezIKaikWNjBOG2wAGlihUQlEmRT5JVVkdW09A0ItTijcPFiQsEYoEDtSNriqWgYk8Ez2wWExSW782JNPc2h4JGQAIXwiNqcoEScARk5qKFB6fiWVpwAmThAWRWhjUwQAGzhKSjnIkWYnMWTkYBfriHyH7lnarEcuQmFAwgEQJx5rpWv1kMtVhtkAAiZF9OEIo6cNZjDxXMTUIJ6IIhMIQSIxNogCAAd0eqGer2p4DkWnRJFZ5XkdTh8IOx2QhzGWkqhCAA

Comment: @prudhvi just made the playground above - a few issues I see. B_Component isn't implementing A<B> - not sure what you're trying to do there...

Comment: @MrRobboto I just fixed the issue. ```B_Component``` is now changed to have a property called ```type``` which is part of interface ```A<B>```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your function signature

```
declare function create_C<T>(a1: A<T>, a2: (obj: any) => T): C<T>;
```

there are two inference sites for `T` (an "inference site" means "someplace the compiler can use to try to infer a type for a type parameter").  One site is from the `type` property of the first argument `a1`, and the other site is the return type of the second argument `a2`. The compiler looks at a call like

```
create_C(new B_Component(), () => ({ prop2: 2 });
```

and tries to infer `T` from both sites.  In this case, there is a match: both `(new B_Component()).type` and `{prop2: 2}` are assignable to `{prop2: number}`.  So there's no error, and you get `C<{prop2: number>` coming out. In another situation, this might be exactly the behavior you want from the compiler.

---

Instead, you want to see the compiler use just `a1` to infer `T`, and to just verify that `a2` matches it.  That is, you want the `T` in `(obj: any) => T` to be a [non-inferential type parameter (see microsoft/TypeScript#14829)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  Unfortunately, there is no "official" support for this.  But fortunately, there are workaround techniques which can often be used to get this behavior.

Here's one such technique: if you change a type parameter in an inference site from `T` to `T & {}`, it [lowers the site's priority](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731).  So the compiler will tend to infer `T` from other inference sites first and only come back to the `T & {}` one if it fails to infer from other places.  And the type `T & {}` is very similar to `T` (if `T` is an object type then it's basically the same) so it doesn't change the semantics much.  Let's try it:

```
declare function create_C_better<T>(a: A<T>, b: (obj: any) => T & {}): C<T>;
```

Here goes:

```
const c2 = create_C_better(
    new B_Component(),
    () => ({ prop2: 2 }) // error!
    //    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- prop1 is missing
)

const c3 = create_C_better(
    new B_Component(),
    () => ({ prop1: "all right", prop2: 2 })
); // C<B>
```

There, you get the error you wanted when `prop1` is missing, and when you fix it, you get an output of type `C<B>` as desired.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-1jcaOY4sYBHWY81ESC0AZmtOKleNlzidQhdfVO53d4GptKE3saTOzQOQwLgEQiyBmDAAFmAwX3A1yeXxkHGMC9iEA)

Comment: Great explanation. Should be referenced in the code because no one will ever know what the `&{}` is for

Answer (score -1):

It is due to the `secondArgument: (obj: any) => T`.
If you apply above definition to `() => ({ prop2: 2 })`
Type of `T` is `{ prop2: number }`. You may change it to something else to get the desired result.
For example.

```
    interface C<T> {
      firstArgument: A<T>;
      secondArgument: (obj: any) => any;
    }

    export interface A<T> {
      type: T;
    }

    declare function create_C<T>(
      firstArgument: A<T>,
      secondArgument: (obj: any) => any
    ): C<T>;

    interface B {
      prop1: string;
      prop2: number;
    }

    export class B_Component implements A<B> {
      type: B;
      configuration: B = {
        prop1: "",
        prop2: 1
      };
    }
    const b = new B_Component();
    export const c = create_C(b, () => ({ prop2: 2 }));
```

Comment: Hey, that thing that you posted still does not work. Type of T is STILL { prop2: number }

Comment: That's strange. Please check this ts playground link. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=15&pln=21&pc=1#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgGEA8AVAfMAN4BQooCYcAzlAIJwDmArgLYzQBcwtueA3KTLAqMFAHsIAE3rM2nYAAoxAIwBWXJBACeASmABeApq0CyAX2KCQMAB4AHMXCjho8ZGm68iV0FC12YLhxTUAsfSVEAGyQ4dAQmCBQoMAlgFFikWAB9bHwFHxAKajpGVnYoLh58ABoC4VEJaVK5CsUVdWBjPUNO7R8dLlz+SzJIWERUdAAhbyFgOzgxOwBGLho4SAYQsgWlgCYuCFZleG3gMLJbByc06KoqYCmcsRYHCHLwV8iYFoeeKYIJDmfgCXCmZxA4ggFGYcEyKQgYIMszm80WKy4ACJMbVUWj9lxlnUzGcLGQoTRgMpke8AO6PZ6vCTlBQ6M5XRzOClc5HpGCZGA5BTKaqKboEBSEfF2A7APbnHRsoA Mouse over on `c` is the expected type.

Comment: But it does not enforce the return type of the 2nd argument to be B

Comment: I got your point. like the first answer ` (obj: any) => T & {}` should fix it.